# How to add tinted mask with text over images on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, hover

[image: my image]

Looking to achieve the effect in the image above.  I have a bunch of svg icons.  When the user hovers over each image, the image tints and white text is revealed unique to each icon.

What's the best practice for this effect?  Make the icons the background image?  Right now they are inline svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layer the image and an invisible overlay `<div>`. Then, on hover, make the overlay visible.

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  min-height: 500px;
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-wrap .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font: 30px sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  background-color: #5fa1e1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.image-wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.menu-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <a href="#" class="image-wrap">
    <img class="menu-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/vgpoAdA.png" />
    <div class="overlay">Basement<br/>Remodel</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `opacity: 0;` on image hover, in your case you can choose SVG image, try this code :

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  min-height: 500px;
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;  
}

.image-wrap .overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color:white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition:opacity .5s ease;
  z-index: 0;
}

.image-wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="#" class="image-wrap">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/vgpoAdA.png" alt="" />
       <div class="overlay image">
        <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/3ONfync.png" />
        <p id="text">
               Rebasement Remodel
        </p>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but you have the right image becoming the left image on hover.  I want to add the blue tint with the text over the left image so it looks similar to the right image.